# Installing pear package using puppet

Tags: puppet, pear

I am trying to install the pear package "HTTP_Request2" using puppet. The target OS is RHEL 7.

I have come across 2 puppet modules that I believe should be able to do this

1. https://forge.puppetlabs.com/rafaelfc/pear
2. https://forge.puppetlabs.com/example42/php

Ideally I would like to use the refaelfc module as it seems more specialized for this task. The problem I have with this is that to gain internet access on the target server you need to go through a proxy, I can't seem to find anything in this module to set this. Without this set puppet just times out when trying to install the module.

Using option 2 I add the following to my manifest:

```
    include php
    php::pear::config { http_proxy: value => "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx" }
    php::pear::module { 'HTTP_Request2':
            repository  => 'pear.phpunit.de',
            alldeps => 'true',
            require => Php::Pear::Config['http_proxy'],
    }
```

When doing this I get the error:

```
Error: Execution of '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list php-pear-HTTP_Request2' returned 1: Error: No matching Packages to list
```

It doesn't seem right to be that it should be calling on yum? How can I get puppet to install this pear package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working using a combination of the example42/php module and a custom script:

```
    include php
    php::pear::config { http_proxy:
             value => "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx",
    }
    exec { 'HTTP_Request2':
            command => '/usr/bin/pear install HTTP_Request2',
            unless  => '/usr/bin/pear info HTTP_Request2',
            require => Php::Pear::Config['http_proxy'],
    }
```